# Pinescript plotshapes assistance required

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I have made an custom indicator in TradingView which plots arrows whenever buy or sell conditions are met.

Here is the code:-

```
Pinescript version = 5

//RSI Calculation
rsiValue = ta.rsi(close,14)

//Variables for storing RSI condition

rsiBuy = (rsiValue > 30) ? 1 : 0
rsiSell = (ta.crossunder(rsiValue, 70)) ? 1 : 0

//Exponential MA Code
EMA10 = ta.ema(close,10)

GoLong = (ta.crossover(close, EMA10)) or (rsiBuy > 0) ? 1 : 0
plotshape(GoLong, "Long", shape.arrowup, location.belowbar, color.green, size = size.normal)

ExitLong = ta.crossunder(close, EMA10) or (rsiSell > 0) ? 1 : 0
plotshape(ExitLong, "ExitLong", shape.arrowdown, location.abovebar, color.orange, size = size.normal)
```

The issue I am facing:-

a) The GoLong plots an arrow for every bar which meets either condition without checking if the ExitLong condition has fired for the earlier GoLong.

b) The ExitLong also plots an arrow for every bar that meets the conditions without checking if a GoLong condition has been initiated earlier.

What code do I need to add to make both GoLong and ExitLong check for each other before plotting the arrows for subsequent bars meeting Long and Exit conditions?

I tried For and While Loops but I think they failed to achieve my requirement only because of my inferior knowledge of Pinescript.
Any help would be much appreciated !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should record the state of your trade, and then decide to go long or exit.

Like this :

```
//RSI Calculation
rsiValue = ta.rsi(close,14)

//Variables for storing RSI condition

rsiBuy = (rsiValue > 30) ? 1 : 0
rsiSell = (ta.crossunder(rsiValue, 70)) ? 1 : 0

//Exponential MA Code
EMA10 = ta.ema(close,10)

var InLong = false
GoLong = false
ExitLong = false

ConditionGoLong = (ta.crossover(close, EMA10)) or (rsiBuy > 0) ? 1 : 0
if ConditionGoLong and not(InLong)
    GoLong := true
    ExitLong := false
    InLong := true

plotshape(GoLong, "Long", shape.arrowup, location.belowbar, color.green, size = size.normal)

ConditionExitLong = ta.crossunder(close, EMA10) or (rsiSell > 0) ? 1 : 0
if ConditionExitLong and InLong
    ExitLong := true
    GoLong := false
    Inlong := false

plotshape(ExitLong, "ExitLong", shape.arrowdown, location.abovebar, color.orange, size = size.normal)
```

Comment: Thanks ! 

This solved the issue partially.

The GoLong condition now waits for the ExitLong condition.

However, the ExitLong still plots arrows for either or both conditions met even if there is no GoLong in between.

Comment: @samir7399 the plot of the exitlong arrows can only be plotted if ExitLong is true...  I Can you update your question with the entire code of your script ?

Comment: Apologies ! It was my mistake that I typed something wrong.

I have since corrected it and now the code works as I require it to be.

Many thanks again for helping me with this !